# Find and replace a specific pattern

Tags: r

I have a large data.frame in which the first column looks like:

> "COL"
> ELOVL6
> ELOVL7
> ELP2
> EMC1 (includes EG:23065)
> EPT1 (includes EG:28042)
> ZEB1 (includes EG:29009)

I would like to remove all the (includes EG:...) to have the following output:

> "COL"
> ELOVL6
> ELOVL7
> ELP2
> EMC1
> EPT1
> ZEB1

Any suggestion about this?

Comment: please dput your data, please?

Comment: dput(tmp1)
structure(list(Symbol = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3806L, 
3806L, 3806L, 3806L, 14971L, 14971L, 14976L, 14978L, 14978L,....), class = "factor")), .Names = "Symbol", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-54613L))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this....

```
COL <- c("ELOVL7",
         "ELP2",
         "EMC1 (includes EG:23065)",
         "EPT1 (includes EG:28042)",
         "ZEB1 (includes EG:29009)")

COL <- data.frame(COL)
data.frame(COL=sapply(strsplit(as.character(COL[,1]), split=" "), '[', 1))
     COL
1 ELOVL7
2   ELP2
3   EMC1
4   EPT1
5   ZEB1
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 I suppose y your column of the data.frame

 sapply(as.list(y),function(x){gsub("(.*)\\(.*\\)", "\\1", x)})
```

**EDIT**

even more simpler

```
 gsub("(.*)\\(.*\\)", "\\1", x)
```

Comment: The `sapply` doesn't seem necessary? `gsub` is works vectorized.